# Prevent Numpy Loadtxt from Removing Leading Zeros

Tags: python, numpy, loading

I have a data file that contains a column that is like this

```
000100
000101
000102
000103
etc.
```

I am reading it, and other columns in using numpy.loadtxt to get an array containing all the information in the file, which is then going through further processing

loadtxt seems to remove the leading zeros, so that I end up with a column like this

```
100
101
102
103
etc.
```

I need the leading zeros kept as they are important - is there any way to prevent it from cropping them?

Comment: what `dtype` are you specifying?

Comment: You'll have to use a string data type.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import numpy

path = "test.txt"

array = numpy.loadtxt(path, dtype=numpy.int32, converters={0: lambda x: int(x, base=2)})
```

Be sure to specify a **dtype**, depending on what you want because, by default, numpy does everything as a **float**

Comment: `100` looks like a int, not a float.  Ints don't have leading 0s